# ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused - MQTT

Tags: sockets, client, mqtt, broker

I am very new to socket and communication using MQTT. Already spent hours but dont know what is wrong. Kindly help me to fix this error.
I am using the below code,

```
import socket
import json
from random import randint
from inference import Network
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt

HOSTNAME = socket.gethostname()
IPADDRESS = socket.gethostbyname(HOSTNAME)
MQTT_HOST = IPADDRESS
MQTT_PORT = 1883 ### TODO: Set the Port for MQTT
MQTT_KEEPALIVE_INTERVAL = 60

client = mqtt.Client()
client.connect(MQTT_HOST,MQTT_PORT,MQTT_KEEPALIVE_INTERVAL)
```

And the error and traceback is shown below,

```
(venv) root@119d16139409:/home/workspace# python app.py | ffmpeg -v warning -f rawvideo -pixel_format bgr24 -video_size 1280x720 -framerate 24 -i - http://0.0.0.0:3004/fac.ffm
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 145, in <module>
    main()
  File "app.py", line 141, in main
    infer_on_video(args, model)
  File "app.py", line 74, in infer_on_video
    client.connect(MQTT_HOST,MQTT_PORT,MQTT_KEEPALIVE_INTERVAL)
  File "/opt/intel/openvino_2019.3.376/deployment_tools/model_optimizer/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 937, in connect
    return self.reconnect()
  File "/opt/intel/openvino_2019.3.376/deployment_tools/model_optimizer/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 1071, in reconnect
    sock = self._create_socket_connection()
  File "/opt/intel/openvino_2019.3.376/deployment_tools/model_optimizer/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 3522, in _create_socket_connection
    return socket.create_connection(addr, source_address=source, timeout=self._keepalive)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socket.py", line 711, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socket.py", line 702, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

Comment: Edit the code to print out the values of `MQTT_HOST` so we can see where it is trying to conecnt to. Replace the screen shot of the error with the actual text (images are impossible to search for).  Also you have tagged this as Websockets, but there is no use of websockets anywhere in the code provided, you might want to include the broker configuration.

Comment: I am not able to print the MQTT_HOST. It throws another error which is completely irrelavant

Comment: Which implies it's not a valid IP address. Work backwards and see where it's not getting anything useful

Comment: Hi, I could print the MQTT_HOST = '172.18.0.2'. The error comes only when I run 'client.connect(MQTT_HOST,MQTT_PORT,MQTT_KEEPALIVE_INTERVAL)

Comment: Ok, you still haven't edited the question to include your broker config, so we can't see if it's setup right. Also have you checked if there is a firewall on the machine?

Comment: Isn't MQTT_HOST suppose to be in the form of a URI?  IE> "https://mqtt_broker.my.io" or "mqtt://mqtt_broker.my.io" ??